# How to approximate `dpkg --get-selections` from a backup of /etc and /var?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I'm trying to rebuild a Debian system from a recent backup.

All the recipes for doing this that I've found begin with a step of the form

```
dpkg --get-selections > package_list
```

This, of course, must be done on the original system, while all I have is an `rsync` backup on an external drive.  This backup, however, includes all of `/etc` and most<sup>1</sup> of `/var`.

Is there a convenient way to replicate/approximate the output of `dpkg --get-selections` from the contents of `/etc` and `/var`?

---

<sup>1</sup> Excluded from the backup are `/var/{tmp,run,lock}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to retrieve the selections is the `status` file (from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` or one of its backups, `/var/lib/dpkg.status*`), and an `updates` directory alongside it. Then you can run

```
dpkg --admindir=/mnt/backup/var/lib/dpkg/ --get-selections
```

to retrieve the package selections.

Once you've restored the installed packages, and before you do anything else to the rebuilt system, you might want to restore `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` from the backup — that will restore the "automatically installed" flags.