# Where does Debian store the list of installed packages?

Tags: package-management

I need to find a list of the packages that were installed on a Debian (Armbian) sever before it died. Since it's offline, I can't use `apt` or `dpkg` (or any other command). I need to know **which file(s)** contain the list (even if they're binary). I tried searching, but everything just says to run the aforementioend commands, which isn't an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to approximate `dpkg --get-selections` from a backup of /etc and /var?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/301768/86440) addresses your underlying concern.

The list of installed packages is stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`. Look for `Status: install ok installed` lines — this indicates that the package is correctly installed.

The following AWK invocation will extract the installed package names from a `status` file:

```
awk '/^Package:/ { package = $2 }
     /^Status: install ok installed/ { print package }' /path/to/status
```

If the system supported multiple architectures, you’ll need to keep track of that too:

```
awk '/^Package:/ { p = $2; i = 0 }
     /^Status: install ok installed/ { i = 1 }
     i && /^Architecture: all/ { print p; next }
     i && /^Architecture/ { printf "%s:%s\n", p, $2 }' /path/to/status
```

Another interesting file is `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` which records the “automatic installation” flag for installed packages. You can restore the flags by running something like

```
awk '/^Package:/ { p = $2 }
     /^Architecture/ { a = $2 }
     /^Auto-Installed: 1/ { printf "%s:%s\n", p, a }' /path/to/extended_states |
xargs sudo apt-mark auto
```

You can combine both files to list the packages that were manually installed, and rely on dependency management to install the automatically-installed packages (although this won’t necessarily result in the same set of packages being installed):

```
awk 'FNR == NR && /^Package:/ { p = $2 }
     /^Status: install ok installed/ { i = 1 }
     FNR == NR && i && /^Architecture: all/ { ps[p] = 1; next }
     FNR == NR && i && /^Architecture/ { ps[p ":" $2] = 1}
     FNR != NR && /^Package:/ { p = $2 }
     FNR != NR && /^Architecture:/ { a = $2 }
     /^Auto-Installed: 1/ { delete ps[p ":" a] }
     END { for (p in ps) print p }' /path/to/status /path/to/extended_states
```

See the “FILES” section in [`man dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/dpkg/dpkg.1#FILES):

> */var/lib/dpkg/status*
> Statuses of available packages. This file contains information about whether a package is marked for removing or not, whether it is installed or not, etc.

Comment: For completeness, it may help to state where `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates` or `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` fit in the picture (wasn't there a `dselect` one as well before?). The list of installed packages can also be derived from the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/info` (`print -rC1 - /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list(:t:r)` in zsh for instance)

Comment: `/var/lib/aptitude/pkgstates` is only used by `aptitude`. `/var/lib/apt/extended_states` seems more relevant ;-). The `debconf` file is only used by `debconf`-enabled packages. There might have been a `dselect` state file but I’m not sure there are many `dselect` users nowadays... `/var/lib/dpkg/info` can be misleading, files can survive there even though the corresponding packages are gone.

Comment: I've looked in all of those locations and it looks like they've got an extensive list of many sub-packages (some packages cause a lot of dependencies to be installed). Is there a way to see just the stuff that was installed manually without the dependencies? (`/var/log/apt/history.log` looked promising, but it only has the last command, and `/var/log/apt/eipp.log.xz` seems to just be a generic list of all packages including dependencies.) Dependencies can be automatically removed when the main package is removed, so ostensibly, there's a flag or something to indicate that. 

Comment: @Synetech yes, there is a flag, see the part in my answer about `extended_states`. I can update my answer to explain how to combine the two files to get a list of non-automatically-installed packages; but restoring that won’t necessarily produce the same system state as you’d get by restoring all the packages listed in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`.

Comment: I noticed that at least one package isn't listed in any of the files: `Pi-hole`. I installed that without `apt` (directly from their website), are programs installed that way listed anywhere? (In my case, it shouldn't matter because I think that was the only one, but others that might find there way here might have more installed that.)

Comment: @Synetech `dpkg` only knows about packages, not programs which are installed “directly”. There’s no standard way of finding such programs; you’d have to look at the contents of `/usr/local`, `/opt` etc. and hope the program didn’t install itself in system-owned directories (`/usr/bin` etc.).

Comment: That's what I figured. I prefer portable programs in Windows because it's much cleaner than using installers, but this is the downside of that, no central database of what's installed. 